# how to use codebeside in ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net

I'm using VS2008 and want to create a web application (not a web site) with Code-Beside
but, the default mode of aspx is Code-Behind.
I have tried to change the CodeBehind=ClassFile.cs to CodeFile=ClassFile.cs in the header of aspx's <%@Page%> part, and deleted the aspx.designer.cs file,but if I added a server control to the page, the compiler is also send me an error of no member defined.the cs file is the orinal file of codebehind, it is partial class.

Comment: but, why asp.net website doesn't need the designer.cs file, it looks tidy.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to delete aspx.designer.cs you want to delete the aspx.cs file, then place a similar file next to it and declare it as a partial class. designer.aspx.cs is still required to provide you direct access to controls placed within the page, rather than going through FindControl.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't want to delete the .designer.cs file, as this is where the server control definitions will be placed.

In general the codebehind model is *much* better as it makes the code easier to find, use and maintain.